# (iphone) Is there a way to see compile output of xcode4?

Tags: iphone, build, xcode4

as in question, How can I see compile output of xcode4?

Thank you

Comment: you mean output at compile time?

Comment: compilation output(build output).. xcodebuild's output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could see the build/Compile output in the **issue navigator**  and **log navigator**

Follow the below simple step to go to the **issue navigator**
Open XCode 4,

Build your project, then

press **command + 4** for **issue navigator**. (there are two filter here "**By File**" and "**By Type**")

press **command + 7** for **log navigator** (contain compile information for  all day build).

Answer (score 2):

Press MAC key (command) + shift + B to show build output.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to take the build created after compiling, it can be obtained from the build\Release-iphonesimulator\app-name folder