# Xcode 4 is no longer showing me where my warnings are?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Xcode 4 has stopped showing me the locations of build warnings that I have. How can i get it to start showing me them again?

Comment: Any more details?  Did you just change from XCode 3 to 4, or ?  Did you click on the little warning icon in the status display in the top middle?

Comment: You've tried quitting and restarting XCode 4, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're looking in the right place.  On the left-hand side of Xcode (4), look for the little error symbol.  Click it and enjoy your errors in all their glory.

[image]

If you click on the errors and it doesn't take you to the location in code, I think something must be messed up with your Xcode install.  I remember you had another question earlier about Xcode problems, so it wouldn't hurt to uninstall & reinstall.

Comment: I think you're right about the uninstall. Bit annoying, i never had any problems with xcode 3.

Comment: 4.0.2. It's just annoying. First, it crashes so I can't fix my errors. Now, it's telling me in the sidebar there's an error, but not showing me where abouts.

Comment: Strange.  Yeah, I'd suggest completely removing Xcode and all related preferences.  You can remove those by deleting `~/Library/Developer/` (notice it's the developer contained in the library in your home folder, not your root directory).  Delete that, in addition to running the uninstall script found in the installation guide.  Depending on where you installed it, you can run this in the terminal to uninstall it: `sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all`.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 4.3.1. I have one project that doesn't show any warnings, but others do.

So it's not an Xcode issue I guess.

Answer (score 1):

In the Issue Navigator (⌘4) be sure to clear the filter at the bottom left of the screen:
 [image: Issue Navigator filter]

Just click on the x at the right, at the filter will be removed -- worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Check the below SO post

[(iphone) Is there a way to see compile output of xcode4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800420/iphone-is-there-a-way-to-see-compile-output-of-xcode4/5800499#5800499)

press **command + 4** for issue navigator. (there are two filter here "`By File`" and "`By Type`")